# Retrieve IP of current server in Javascript to fetch a text file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple Javascript application that formats and displays text from a CSV file located on the same server as the HTML and Javascript website.

I want to read the text from CSV file without hard coding the IP address of the server

Right now I am using something like this

```
window.onload = () => {
    addr_of_csv = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/csvfile.csv"
        
    fetchText(addr_of_csv).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

What is the best practice to load the text file without using the IP address stored in a string?

I tried to use something like `var ip = request.getRemoteHost();` but it did not find the request library.
How would I implement it? please provide full code including the `import` line.

Or is there a way to enter a relative path to the current directory of the Javascript file?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use a relative file path? `addr_of_csv = "/csvfile.csv"` If it's on the same server, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, if you would like to use relative path or not, but this function can work with both

```
function readTextFile(file) {
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
{
    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
    {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        alert(allText);
    }
}
}
rawFile.send(null);
}
```

and then call it as

```
readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
readTextFile("http://test/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the IP address of a server directly using JavaScript, just the host name.

There are two solutions to your quest:

**1. Use external DNS lookup**

Do a REST call to a DNS service that has the proper CORS settings, such as https://dohjs.org/. This implies that your host is defined in a public name service, e.g. won't work for hosts inside a firewall.

**2. Create a REST endpoint that returns the IP address**

On your server add a new endpoint that returns the IP address. E.g. call this before you call your get CSV endpoint.